# How to create a custom form in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have three entities : Service, Group, Agent.

**Service** => oneToMany => **Group** => oneToMany => **Agent**

Each of these entities already have a form. By the way, I would like to create a custom mergeForm which will contains a select field **Service** to choose and a select field **Groupe** in order to merge some of these entities. The Symfony 2 official cookbook is under maintenance, so I would like to know the way to create the custom Form in which I will be able to choose a Service (from all existing services) and to choose a Group (from all existing groups)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I thank you. This morning the website was unavailable (maybe offline) and I wasn't able to go on. Now it's ok, and I found an solution ; create a MergeType, a Form Component in which I can retrieve services and groups list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).  This will allow you to embed within the form a select field that points to the foreign entity.  This is primarily useful for small collections.

When you start dealing with large collections, and find the need/desire to load entities with Javascript (e.g. The collection is to large to justify loading all on page-load), you'll have to look at [Symfony2 Documentation: How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

It's also worth noting that there is a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1951) slated for Symfony 2.2 that is supposed to make dealing with this type of form easier.